# How to set dynamic value in css?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I want to pass dynamic css value.I want to change css value on index basis.

```
<hr style="width: 150px;float: left;position: absolute;z-index: 99999;top: 28%;margin-left:110px; left: (index == 0) ? '110px' : '145px'%;">
```

but the here "left" value is not taken by html.
How can i fix it?

Comment: You can't. CSS is not *dynamic*. You need javascript.

Comment: if javascript is a soluation than please explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make angular evaluate the expression once, use the double curly braces as usual:

```
<hr style="width: 150px;float: left;position: absolute;z-index: 99999;top: 28%;margin-left:110px; left: {{(index == 0) ? '110px' : '145px'}};">
```

To do it continuously, try this:

```
<hr style="width: 150px;float: left;position: absolute;z-index: 99999;top: 28%;margin-left:110px;" [style.left]="(index == 0) ? '110px' : '145px'">
```

Comment: Thanks it's works for me

Comment: i want to write this in css file so i am trying like this--- hr{left:(index==0)?'110px':'145px'} but it not going to effective.please give a suggestion.

Comment: You can't do this from CSS.

Comment: than what is the option for this I have to apply media query at different screen size how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

`ngStyle` allows you to do that:

```
<hr [ngStyle]="{width: '150px', float: 'left', position: 'absolute', 'z-index': 99999, top: '28%', 'margin-left':'110px', left: (index == 0) ? '110px' : '145px'%}">
```

or

```
<hr style="width: 150px;float: left;position: absolute;z-index: 99999;top: 28%;margin-left:110px;" 
    [ngStyle]="{left: (index == 0) ? '110px'}"> : '145px'%;">
```